# function cannot access 'xxx::xxx::operator <<'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I have some code like:

```
namespace xxx {
   namespace xxx {
     struct local {
        static void xxxxx(....) {
           std::cout << "prints..........." <<std::endl;
        }
     }
}}
```

And I get errors as the title stated: "function cannot access 'xxx::xxx::operator <<'"

I created the MSVC project with visual studio 2005. While when I open the project in visual studio 2010, everyting works fine. But I need it working visual studio 2005, what might be the reason for it?

When I open it from Visual Studio 2010, I didn't change anything, it works directly.

And I know it is working with gcc as well. So something I can do for the msvc project to make it working without changing the code?

Comment: @Bathsheba Thx, my fault. It is typo, upadted.

Comment: More of the code may be needed ... like the include directives... and be certain that the only instances of 'operator <<' really are in the 'std::cout'. I don't have access to VS2005 to reproduce this... A quick check: place the dreaded "using namespace std;" inside the xxxx declaration, limiting its scope, and remove the "std::" prefixes, to isolate the problem.